# Как правильно присвоить детям ссылку на родительский объект?

Tags: javascript

Построил дерево: папки, в них вложенные папки и файлы.

Стандартная схема parent -> children (упрощённая):

```
{
  "0": {
    "type": "folder",
    "children": [{
      "0": {
        "type": "folder",
        "children": [{
          "0": {
            "type": "file",
            "children": []
          },
          "1": {
            "type": "file",
            "children": []
          }
        }]
      },
      "1": {
        "type": "file",
        "children": []
      }
    }]
  },
  "1": {
    "type": "folder",
    "children": []
  }
}
```

Поиск произвожу рекурсивным методом.
Для удобства и скорости поиска каждому дочернему элементу (при построении дерева) добавил ссылки на его родительский объект. Получилось такое:

```
...
"children": [
  {
    "0": {
      "type": "folder",
      "parent": Object,
      "children": [
        {
          "0": {
            "type": "file",
            "parent": Object,
            "children": []
          },
          "1": {
            "type": "file",
            "parent": Object,
            "children": []
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
```

В итоге получаем следующую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. у объекта есть дети, у которых есть родитель, у которого есть дети, у которого есть родитель... И так далее.
Почему-то не предусмотрел этот момент сразу.

Я не совсем понимаю: каждая ссылка на объект занимает место в памяти? Если так, то почему не крашится приложение: их же будет бесконечное множество? Может быть, эти ссылки на объект ленивые и отображаются только в браузере? Т.е. пока не воспользуешься, их попросту нет?

Как лучше искать родительский объект? Я сперва parentId указывал у каждого дочернего элемента, но, к примеру, файл лежит в папках на 10 уровней вложенности. И если известен лишь parentId, то придётся 10 раз пробегаться по дереву. Обратиться к уже известному объекту куда быстрее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = {};
var b = {};
a.children = b;
b.parent = a;
console.log(a);
```

[Пример в JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6xnebaj/)

По факту ссылок всего две: на детей у родителя и на родителя у детей. Поэтому приложение работает нормально, а подобный подход вполне имеет право на существование.

Ходить же по кругу, переходя от ссылки к ссылке, можно сколько угодно (по крайней мере, покуда у браузера будут ресурсы на отрисовку всех переходов)

---

В качестве сравнения можно привести такой пример:

На выезде из деревни Родичи есть указатель "Деткино, 5км", а выезде из Деткино - "Родичи, 5км". В итоге, указателей установлено ровно 2 штуки, по одному на каждом конце дороги. А вот мотаться из одной деревни в другую, каждый раз записывая себе в блокнот маршрут ("Родичи -> Деткино" или "Деткино -> Родичи") можно до тех пор, пока есть силы двигаться или пока не кончится блокнот

Comment: Спасибо, значит всё правильно сделал.